# Issue rendering child views in Vue with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having trouble getting my child views to render in Vue.

My main.js file looks like this

```
import DashboardProducts from './components/Dashboard/DashboardProducts'
import DashboardSettings from './components/Dashboard/DashboardSettings'


Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuex)

const routes = [
  { path: '/activate', component: Activate },
  { path: '/dashboard/:view', component: Dashboard, 
    children: [ 
      { path: 'products', component: DashboardProducts },
      { path: 'settings', component: DashboardSettings }
    ]
  },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
  { path: '/account', component: UserAccount }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
});

export default router;


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

As you can see I have imported the components and get no errors. I have also added them as children of Dashboard and set their paths.

In my Dashboard.vue view I do this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <dashboard-nav></dashboard-nav>

        <!-- Will display product and settings components -->
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DashboardNav from '../components/Dashboard/DashboardNav'

export default {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    components: {
        DashboardNav
    }
};

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Urls are matching but no components are rendering. What am I missing?

Here is a JSFiddle of pretty much what I'm going for https://jsfiddle.net/dtac5m11/

It seems to be working fine there but I'm also using single file components in my app so it may be a little different?

Again, the issue is getting the child components to render when their routes match. Currently no components are being mounted.

**UPDATE:**

I am getting the `DashboardProducts` component to render but can't get `DashboardSettings` to render.

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: could you tell us what is the issue? 
Try to create webpack bin with your content

Comment: The issue is child components aren't rendering when their routes match. I have a JS Fiddle here where it seems to be working fine but can't figure out why it isn't working in my app https://jsfiddle.net/dtac5m11/

Comment: We may need to see the full repository to figure out.

Comment: @CodinCat Link to repo https://github.com/MaxwellGover/shelf/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: I clone the repository, and I can see the DashboardSettings

Comment: Oops.. I think I got your problem. Nazgul is correct

Comment: The answer depends on what you want, `/dashboard/foo/settings` or `/dashboard/settings`

Comment: @CodinCat Getting it to work with `/dashboard/settings` would be ideal b/c then I know I can always go to `/dashboard/foo/settings` if I want to and it will work.

Comment: Just use `/dashboard` instead of `/dashboard/:view`, then it will work on /dashboard/settings

Comment: Also, remove the slash of `/settings`, just `path: 'settings'`

Comment: Ok. I also had to change the code in my navigation component from `router.push({ path: '/dashboard/settings'});` to `router.push({ path: '/dashboard'});`. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ path: '/dashboard/:view', component: Dashboard,
```

At first, for what purpose do you add :view after dashboard path? If you are using this one for children path as a parameter, it is an issue. It is the reason, why your children component are not rendering. Because, :view is for dynamic routes. /dashboard/:view is equivalent to /dashboard/* and it means that after /dashboard there can be any route and this route will render Dashboard component. And your children paths /dashboard/products and /dashboard/settings will always match /dashboard/:view and render parent component-Dashboard. 
So, in your case, your routes for children components are known. So you do not need to use :view.
More, https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html.

Comment: If you want to use routes something like /dashboard/3/products or /dashboard/ex/products..  yeah it is right, but your route is /dashboard/products, am i right?

Comment: Yeah. I make the changes you suggest and now I'm just getting a blank screen. Nothing is rendering. I get what you're saying though. I wonder why it's not working!? :(

Comment: Ok. Tried that and nothing. Dashboard component not even mounting. No errors in the console or anything either. Don't get how that's even possible.

Comment: `dashboard` component renders at path `/dashboard` and component mounts but when navigating to `/dashboard/settings` component unmounts and nothing renders to the page.